# Adding a toggling pause/play function to my image slideshow

Tags: jquery

I am extremely new to this. I found some script for a simple slideshow. That same poster offered more script to add Previous & Next buttons to his script. It all works great and I love it. But I want to add a pause button that will stop the slideshow upon clicking and restart it when clicked again. I am not interested in the look of the button changing, just want the fucntion to toggle. I have created my button and placed it where I want it and it is called "pauseButton" in the div. I am not using any specific "plugins" like "Cycle", just regular jquery (I guess). I have spent 4 days looking for answers online and, while some examples may have worked, I am not smart enough to know how to tweak it to fit my script. I just need to know what exactly to add to this (& where) to make it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var flag = true;
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
  if(flag){ 
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
    .next('img').fadeIn()
    .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
  3000);
 }
});
    $(function () {
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
        $('.nextButton').on('click', function () {
            $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                .next('img').fadeIn()
                .end().appendTo('.fadein');
        });
        $('.previousButton').on('click', function () {
            $('.fadein :last-child').fadeIn()
                .insertBefore($('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut());
        });
    $('.pauseButton').click(function(){
         flag = !flag;   
        });
});
</script>
```

Here is the whole page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Thirteen Pine</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var flag = true;         
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
  if(flag){                    
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
        .next('img').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
    3000);
  }
});
    $(function () {
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
        $('.nextButton').on('click', function () {
            $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                .next('img').fadeIn()
                .end().appendTo('.fadein');
        });
        $('.previousButton').on('click', function () {
            $('.fadein :last-child').fadeIn()
                .insertBefore($('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut());
        });
         $('.pauseButton').click(function(){
             flag = !flag;
        });

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.fadein { position:relative; width:450px; height:275px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }

#showcontainer {
    width: 530px;
    height: 315px; }
#btn1 {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px; }
#show {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    height: 275px; }
#btn2 {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px; }
#btn3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px; }

.nextButton, .previousButton, .pauseButton { cursor: pointer }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showcontainer">
  <div id="btn1"><img src="../images/btn_prev.png" width="40" height="80" vspace="100" class="previousButton"/></div>
    <div id="show" class="fadein">
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide1.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide2.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide3.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide4.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide5.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide6.png" width="450" height="275" /> 
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide7.png" width="450" height="275" /> 
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide8.png" width="450" height="275" />           
    </div>    
  <div id="btn2"><img src="../images/btn_next.png" width="40" height="80" vspace="100" class="nextButton"/></div><br />
  <div id="btn3"><img src="../images/btn_pause.png" width="80" height="30" class="pauseButton"/></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and add some HTML to build a working example. You can also supply a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: The poster that shared this code I found hasn't been online in over a year, so I can't just ask him what to do. He seemed fairly new to writing script anyway. I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Post HTML markup! I guess you are using HTML code somewhere... How your comment is relevant to previous comment made by @simbabque?!

Answer (score 3):

You could add a flag variable, and only execute the main code inside your `setInterval` callback if it is true:

```
$(function(){
  var flag = true;
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
  if(flag){
     $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
       .next('img').fadeIn()
       .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
     3000);
  }
});
```

Then bind a click handler to your pause button that toggles the flag:

```
$('#my-button').click(function(){
    flag = !flag;
});
```

Comment: looks simple and efficient +1

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing, but wanted to wait for a working example.

Comment: @simbabque I don't blame you, but I'm in an airport and really bored :)

Comment: I edited my question and included the suggestions you gave me. I put them where I thought they went but it didn't work. It just made the slideshow start on the last pic and stay there.
I also included the entire page since someone wanted the html. My earlier comment wasn't in response to simbabque, I didn't realize there was a comment there when I was simply offering info on why I didn't go to the guy that wrote what I'm using. Please remember that I am stupid and feel quite lucky that my slideshow worked at all. I don't even halfway understand js and have never posted on this site before.